installation error on virtual box
I have been using ubuntu for 2 weeks. I am new user who try to learn ubuntu and linux. SO I accidentally moved the home file and  couldn't bring back. So ı deleted my ubuntu from virtual box. When ı want to install a new ubuntu on virtual box. During installation ı changed basic virtual box username and password. After that ı completed the installation. Ubuntu installation screen is opened and didin't ask me question like clock configuration, keyboard configuration etc. Didn't even ask me if ı want to install or try. Suddenly restared the virtual box. There fore ı couldn't creat a new user. After the restard user login interface is oppened ı try to write password which ı changed on virtual box( because the pc name was the same as the one ı changed on virtual box) and ıt said wrong password. I can't enter my virtual box pc. I deleted everything virtualbox etc. but ı still have the same problem. Literally ı am stuck pls help me
